# How to construct unimodular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, unimodular-matrices

**Definition:** An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries is called unimodular if $\det A = \pm 1$.

For $n=2$, if $a, b$ are coprime integers, by Euclid's algorithm, there exist $x, y$ such that $ax-by=1$. It means matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}a&x\\b&y\end{bmatrix}$$ is an unimodular matrix. I want to do the same technique for $n=3$.

**Problem:** For integers $x,y,z$ such that the greatest common divisor of $x,y,z$ is 1, there exist integers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that $x=  bf-ce, y= cd-af$ and $z= ae-bd$. Is this statement is True?

Comment: Orthogonal matrices is another way to cook up such matrices for any $n$. Just make sure the column vectors are orthonormal.

Comment: @AlvinL The OP wants integer matrices.

Comment: David's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028471/a-quick-way-to-generate-3x3-matrices-with-determinant-equal-to-1) might also be of interest. The diagonal elements can be picked from $\{-1,1\}$ in this case.

Comment: With respect to the Title Question: my suggestion is to create a "random" integer matrix then compute Smith Normal Form, and discard the diagonal matrix... you now have two matrices with unit determinant in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to generate such matrices.

We can assume that
$$\left\lvert\begin{array}{ccc}\pm1&x&y\\0&a&b\\0&c&d\end{array}\right\rvert = \pm 1$$
We can pick $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ arbitrarily and it suffices to guarantee that
$$\left\lvert\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right\rvert =\pm 1.$$

Then we can do elementary row and column operations however we want and the determinant will change between $\pm 1$.

Comment: I think this is how all 3x3 unimodulars are obtained but at the moment I can't think of why at least one column (or row) must have two coprime entries.

Comment: Thank for you answer. But I don't know how to generalize when $x,y,z$ are coprime? How we construct matrix in this case?

Comment: @ĐạtTrầnTấn This approach completely ignores your attempt, I don't know if what you ask is true. I am merely applying some basic properties of determinants to generate unimodulars.